# How video ads workarounds Chrome autoplay policy when autoplaying video with sound?

Tags: google-chrome, audio, video, ads, autoplay

I've tried to find a workaround to autoplay video with sound on and found a couple, but none of them are works for me. Also I've found a tons of replies that this is not possible to autoplay video with sound on, but in the same time I saw a lot of video ads that start playing automatically with sound. So seems like there is a way to make it happen at least for advertisers. I heard about whitelist for websites which are allowed to autoplay with sound such as youtube, but I guess this is not the case for ads. So, does anybody know how could it be implemented that way?

Answer (score 0):

this is the real reason

https://blog.google/products/chrome/improving-autoplay-chrome/

Chrome does this by learning your preferences. If you don’t have browsing history, Chrome allows autoplay for over 1,000 sites where we see that the highest percentage of visitors play media with sound. As you browse the web, that list changes as Chrome learns and enables autoplay on sites where you play media with sound during most of your visits, and disables it on sites where you don’t. This way, Chrome gives you a personalized, predictable browsing experience.

As you teach Chrome, you may find that you need to click “play” every now and then, but overall the new policy blocks about half of unwanted autoplays, so you will have fewer surprises and less unwanted noise when you first arrive at a website. The policy is enabled in the latest version of Chrome—update today and try it out.